# angularfire2 - How to keep data when I navigate away

Tags: angular, angularfire2

The item list is populated on refresh. However, when I navigate to another page and navigate back, the item list is empty. getItems gets called, but the subscription doesn't happen.

This is such a trivial example. What am I doing wrong?

item.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { ItemService } from './item.service';
import { Item } from './item';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-items',
  templateUrl: './items.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./items.component.css']
})
export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {
  items: Item[];

  constructor(private itemService: ItemService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.itemService.getItems().subscribe(items => {
      this.items = items;
    });
  }
}
```

item.service.ts

```
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Item } from './item';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ItemService {
  items: Observable<Item[]>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.items = this.afs.collection<Item>('items').valueChanges();
  }

  getItems() {
    return this.items;
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
  providers: [ItemService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're not unsubscribing when you navigate away from the page, the Observable is still hot and will only emit changes.

There are a couple possible fixes here; either unsubscribe, use `takeUntil` / `takeWhile` and flag when the component is torn down, or put a `replay(1)` / `shareReplay(1)` in your service.

Which of these you choose depend on how large the items collection is, how often it changes, and how you intend to use the service in the future.

```
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Item } from './item';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ItemService {
  items: Observable<Item[]>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.items = this.afs.collection<Item>('items')
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(shareReplay(1));
  }

  getItems() {
    return this.items;
  }
}
```